# Integral sequence

Tags: integration

So we have this sequence, $$I_{n}=\int_0^1\ln(1+x^n)\:dx$$ and we have to show that this is monotone and bounded.
My solution is this: $$x\in[0,1]\implies 0\leq\ln(1+x^n)\leq\ln(2)$$ and if we integrate from $0$ to $1$ we get $$0\leq I_{n}\leq\ln(2)$$ which proves that $I_{n}$ is bounded. Is this correct? 
To show that the sequence is monotone I was thinking about the difference $I_{n}-I_{n+1}$. Is this correct too?$$ $$
!!!EDIT!!! Now we have to show that $I_{n}\leq\frac{1}{n+1},\:\:\forall\:n\in\mathbb{N}$ and to find $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}I_n$.$$$$So, I guess is obvious that $I_n\leq\int_{0}^{1}x^n\:dx$, right???

Comment: For a fixed $x\in(0,1)$, $x^{n+1}< x^n$ implies $\log(1+x^{n+1})<\log(1+x^n)$ and $I_n$ is obviously decreasing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the last question. you can derivate $ln(1+x^n)-x^n$ prove it's decreasing and then for x=0 it's equal 0 so in [0;1] the difference is negative.
then you need to integrate $x^n$ and for the limite use sandwich theorem( also called gent d'arme)

Comment: actually, this is what I did !! thx

Answer (score 1):

What you did is correct. In order to show that $(I_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is monotonic, you do$$\bigl(\forall x\in[0,1]\bigr):1+x^{n+1}\leqslant1+x^n\implies\int_0^1\ln(1+x^{n+1})\,\mathrm dx\leqslant\int_0^1\ln(1+x^n)\,\mathrm dx,$$since $\ln$ is increasing.

Comment: Aaah, sure... easy and nice!! thx a lot!